# Can't update: no tracked branch

Tags: android-studio, git, github

На Github создан пустой репозиторий с именем *ThreadExample*, с одним *README.md* файлом, но при попытке "запушить" из Android Studio проект получаю ошибку:

```
Push rejected: Push to origin/master was rejected
```

При попытке выполнить "merge" из Android Studio получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Can't update: no tracked branch
            No tracked branch configured for branch master.
            To make your branch track a remote branch call, for example,
            git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master

Update canceled
```

при этом из Git Bash команда `$ git remote -v` выводит следующее:

```
origin  https://github.com/Username/ThreadExample (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Username/ThreadExample (push)
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Склонируйте репу заново

Comment: Можно просто `force push` сделать - Readme потрётся, но это, по идее, не страшно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо! force push, по сути, решил проблему. А что могло быть причиной проблемы?..

Comment: @Ksenia, ну, у вас на компе была только локальная мастер ветка, у коей не было ссылки на удалённую. Засим вы не могли `pull` сделать. А `push` нельзя, т.к. на сервере есть такая же по названию ветка в коей есть коммит, коего нет на компе. Для `push` без `force` надо подтянуть изменения с сервера, а это нельзя, т.к. нет адреса для `pull` - в итоге замкнутый круг) Наверное можно решить это ещё и проставлением адреса на сервере (`remote-url`) для локальной ветки `master`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, cпасибо большое за такой подробный комментарий! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на компе есть только локальная мастер ветка, у коей нет ссылки на удалённую. Засим вы не можете `pull` сделать. А `push` нельзя, т.к. на сервере есть такая же по названию ветка в коей есть коммит, коего нет на компе. Для `push` без `force` надо подтянуть изменения с сервера, а это нельзя, т.к. нет адреса для `pull` - в итоге замкнутый круг)

Решить можно или проставлением адреса на сервере (remote-url) для локальной ветки `master` или через `force push`, который перезатрёт историю на сервере.

Comment: А что не так с предлагаемым самим гитом `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master`? После него думаю получится сделать pull (если у репозиториев вообще есть общая история)

Comment: @vp_arth, хм... Ну, вообще, наверное, да, так тоже можно)